# How can I add items in UrlRewrite table?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I want to rewrite an URL via code and I read that I need to write in `core_url_rewrite` table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the backend, go to Catalog->URL Rewrite Management, click on "add new" button and fill in the required fields.

**[EDIT]**
If you want to do it via code, you can do this:

```
$storeId = 1; //replace with your store id

$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');
$rewrite->setStoreId($storeId);
$rewrite->setCategoryId(null); //not for categories
$rewrite->setProductId(null);//not for products
$rewrite->setIsSystem(0); //it's not system generated - it won't get deleted on a reindex.
$rewrite->setRequestPath('from where you want to redirect');
$rewrite->setTargetPath('where you want to redirect');
$rewrite->setIdPath(uniqid()); //generate a random unique id path
$rewrite->setOptions('RP'); //301 redirect - permanent redirect
$rewrite->save();
```

Comment: That I know. Sorry I didn't spoke myself clearly. I mean how can I do that In code. I have an `$oldurl` and `$newurl`.

Comment: @ana.coman93. See my update. I hope it works. "Bafta" :)

Answer (score 0):

1) In case you are looking for doing it programmatically you need to use the model 'core/url_rewrite' to write the URLS to the core_url_rewrite table. You can use this [link](https://gielberkers.com/how-to-programmatically-create-url-rewrites-in-magento-community/) to create Url rewrites programmatically.

2) Magento Also allows Url rewrites via admin panel for which marius has already provided guidance

Answer (score 0):

I think for your requirement you can create 301 url redirect rule in your `.htaccess` file like below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   redirect 301 baseurl/old_url.html  base_url/new_url.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I can't do that because It's not for my personal computer. I am not having acces to that file.

Comment: and also I want to do that multiple times for multiple url's.